# Oracle ADF and SalesForce Integration

Tags: salesforce, integration, oracle-adf, declarative-programming

I am trying to integrate **ADF** application to **SalesForce**. I have my enterprise URL and api-token and password. I am able to call services and get results from soapUI.

Now the challenge is I'd like to integrate salesforce and get data to ADF application. I have created *datacontrol* for SOAP web service. But this'll not work as SalesForce follows a secured approach. First we need to call ***Login()*** service which'll return a dynamic ***serviceURL*** and a ***sessionId***. Then we need to call the desired service with serviceURL as endpoint and sessionId as one of the request attributes. How could I implement this in  declarative approach.

Please do not ask me to write a java client to access SalesForce which I already aware and I am doing.

-V

Answer (score 0):

Create a Java Client Proxy for the various services you want to invoke.
Then create a class with a method that streamline calling those proxies - and expose that class as a data control to use in ADF.

Another approach is to use BPEL with the Oracle SOA suite to orchestrate the sequence of services you are calling.